# Drawing a thick line with legacy OpenGL (immediate mode) in C++

Tags: c++, opengl, line, opengl-compat

i wanted to create a line that is thick using OpenGL library in c++ but it is not working.
i tried this code:

```cpp
glBegin(GL_LINES);
glLineWidth(3);
glVertex2f(-0.7f, -1.0f);
glVertex2f(-0.7f, 1.0f);
glEnd();
```

is there something wrong here?

Comment: Could you please post also a screenshot of what it is showing instead?

Comment: It just shows a thin regular straight line  like 1px wide

Comment: [Use glLineWidth for a particular line without affecting other lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891985), [opengl glLineWidth() doesn't change size of lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34866964)

Comment: This way of programming OpenGL is deprecated since version 3.

Answer (score 6):

Note that rendering with `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences and also `glLineWidth` is deprecated. See [OpenGL Line Width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3484260/opengl-line-width) for a solution using "modern" OpenGL.

---

It is not allowed to call `glLineWidth` with in a `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequence. Set the line width before:

```cpp
glLineWidth(3);

glBegin(GL_LINES);
glVertex2f(-0.7f, -1.0f);
glVertex2f(-0.7f, 1.0f);
glEnd();
```

Once drawing of primitives was started by [`glBegin`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) it is only allowed to specify vertex coordinates ([`glVertex`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetError.xml)) and change attributes (e.g. [`glColor`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml), [`glTexCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoord.xml), etc.), till the drawn is ended (`glEnd`).
All other instruction will be ignored and cause a `GL_INVALID_OPERATION` error, which can be get by [`glGetError`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es2.0/xhtml/glGetError.xml).